# Subset a dictionary in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

How can I subset a dictionary using Python 3? Using Python 2, the below works:

```
global pair_dict

pair_dict = {
    1: 'one',
    2: 'two',
    3: 'three',
    4: 'four',
    5: 'five',
    6: 'six',
    7: 'seven',
    8: 'eight'
}


global test_printer

def test_printer(start_chunk, end_chunk):

    # .items() replacing .iteritems() from Python 2
    sub_dict = dict(pair_dict.items()[start_chunk:end_chunk])
    print sub_dict

test_printer(0, 2)
```

However, in this version of Python I now get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/HTPC Scripts/WebGrab Plus/TESTTESTTEST2.py", line 52, in <module>
    set_chunk_start_end_points()
  File "G:/HTPC Scripts/WebGrab Plus/TESTTESTTEST2.py", line 48, in set_chunk_start_end_points
    test_printer(start_chunk, end_chunk)
  File "G:/HTPC Scripts/WebGrab Plus/TESTTESTTEST2.py", line 27, in test_printer
    sub_dict = dict(pair_dict.values()[start_chunk:end_chunk])
TypeError: 'dict_values' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: What should the expected output be? put the first two items the dict returns into a sub_dict?

Comment: hi...put the first two key/value pairs into a subset.1: 'one',
    2: 'two',

Comment: in my actual code i have an ordered step as well...i just left it out for the sakes of clarity

Comment: well depending on your python version you cant be assured what the first tow items reutrned will be. If you really want to do this you could use `sub_dict = dict(list(pair_dict.items())[start_chunk:end_chunk])`

Answer (score 3):

The issue you are having is just as the error says. The special 'dict_values' object is not subscriptable. If you convert the `pair_dict.items()` / `pair_dict.values()` to a list before trying to subscript them you will get the desired result.

The reason this works in Python2 is that those methods used to return a list object rather than an iterator.

Comment: thanks. im not a full time python dev and ive been using 2.7 for ages and forgotten a lot of the differences to 3.x

Comment: No problem one thing to add is technically dictionaries became ordered by their "insertion" order in some recent version of Python3 - 3.7. See https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html

Answer (score 2):

In python, Dictionaries are not in a specific order, so therefor you cannot subscript them.

One solution to this would be to convert the `dict_values` object to a list.

```
sub_dict = dict(list(pair_dict.items())[start_chunk:end_chunk])
```

However it is probably better to use a `orderedDict` instead of a `dict` if you would like to subscript it.

Comment: hi. i am using an ordereddict in my real code, i just let if out to keep the code easier to follow.